# Write Hex into a file (not as ASCII) in C

Tags: c, file, hex

I'm trying to write a file with hex values representation in C

something like this:

```
char Msg[4] = {0x3f, 0x2a, 0x01, 0x52};
```

the output that I'm looking for into the file is like this: "3f2a0152"

I was using `fprintf` to append some text before the hex representation, but I was not able to write it successfully

```
FILE *LOG_FILE= fopen("./Hex.log", "a");
fprinf(LOG_FILE, "%d OUT %x", Timestamp, Msg);
fclose(LOG_FILE);
```

Any advise?

Comment: Do you mean to ask: "How to print bytes in char array to file as hexadecimal text?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
fprintf(LOG_FILE, "%d OUT %x", Timestamp, Msg);
```

will decay `Msg` to a pointer (address of the `0x3f`) and then print *that* out.

What you need to do is to output each element as a two-digit hex value, something like:

```
fprintf(LOG_FILE, "%d OUT %02x%02x%02x%02x\n", Timestamp, Msg[0], Msg[1], Msg[2], Msg[3]);
```

In addition, they should probably be specified as `unsigned char` so they don't sign-extend when passing to `fprintf`. Otherwise, you'd have to do something ugly like:

```
fprintf(LOG_FILE, "%d OUT %02x%02x%02x%02x\n", Timestamp, (unsigned)(Msg[0]), 
    (unsigned)(Msg[1]), (unsigned)(Msg[2]), (unsigned)(Msg[3]));
```

---

If you wanted a more general solution, you could put together a function to do it, something like:

```
void LogHex(FILE *fh, int tstamp, char *preamble, unsigned char *mem, size_t sz) {
    fprintf(fh, "%d %s", tstamp, preamble);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        fprintf(fh, "%02x", mem[i]);
    }
    fprintf(fh, "\n");
}
:
LogHex(LOG_FILE, Timestamp, "OUT ", Msg, sizeof(Msg));
```

Comment: but what happen when Msg have variable length?

Comment: @Alexis, I've given a better way to do it for variable length buffers.